# How to distribute Flash apps on Android?

Tags: android, flash, google-play

As I know Android Froyo will support Flash 10.1. 
I just wonder how Flash apps could be distributed on Froyo based device.

Will Google allows distribute Flash apps by Android Market?
Or, any other ways for it?

Regards,
Wonil.

Comment: Wouldn't it make a teensy bit more sense to wait until all this stuff is actually announced? I mean, after all, nobody can answer this question yet without getting fired.

Comment: Whats wrong with using Flash inside the browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you'll have 3 ways:

- Flash inside the browser, so not on the Market.
- Flash inside an AIR app.
- Flash inside a native Android app.

The last one I'm not sure about once 10.1 and AIR for Android are ready, but for the time being, *if you target HTC only*, you would be able to do it. I wrote about it: [Running Flash apps on Android/HTC Hero](http://blog.zarate.tv/2009/09/13/running-flash-apps-on-androidhtc-hero/)

Comment: Don't plan on making a habit of that third bullet point. You can launch the player directly like that because it's Flash Lite 3.1, which can run in standalone mode, which 10.1 won't.

Answer (score 2):

*Flash* content is distributed in the browser, embedded into web pages, and that will still be true on Android. If you want apps, then what you'll want to watch for is *AIR* coming to Android, which is also on its way. There are various demos of it floating around ([here's](http://zedomax.com/blog/2010/05/06/adobe-air-on-android-nexus-one-hands-on-review/) a random one).

As for how the apps will be distributed, I don't think that information is out yet, but typically AIR apps are distributed the same way as other apps for that platform.. so the smart money would be that AIR apps will be distributed just like native android apps, through the market mainly or via direct installation if people configure the device to allow it.